# Angular firebase, cant login using factory

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I get an error when i try to login using this code. The part of  creating the user works perfectly and the login methods I used are nearly identical. But chrome gives me this error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.loginUser (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:28:10)
    at Scope.HomeController.$scope.loginUser (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:197:9)
```

This is the html:

```
<button ng-click="createUser(email, password)">Create user</button>
<button ng-click="loginUser(email, password)">Login</button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.createUser = function(email, password) {
    Auth.createUser(email, password); 
}

$scope.loginUser = function(email, password) {
    Auth.loginUser(email, password);
}
```

And the factory:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myQuiz")
        .factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
            var ref = new Firebase("https://angularquiz.firebaseio.com/");

            return {
                createUser: function(email, password) {
                    ref.createUser({
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, function(error, userData) {
                        if(error) {
                            console.log("Error creating user: ", error);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Succesfully created an account with uid: " + userData.uid);
                        }
                    });
                },
                loginUser: function(email, password) {
                    ref.authwithPassword({
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, function(error, authData) {
                        if(error) {
                            console.log("Login failed! " + error);
                        } else {
                            console.log(authData + "Succesfully authenticated!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

typo, its authWithPassword not authwithPassword!

it works now